# Field permission with access token on facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, access-token

I'm requesting graph.facebook.com like that :

```
graph.facebook.com/bordeauxmaville?fields=posts.limit(1).fields(message,picture,created_time,shares,likes,actions)&access_token=MYAPIKEY|MYAPPSECRET
```

You can try it with your own access-token on :

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=bordeauxmaville%3Ffields%3Dposts.limit(1).fields(message%2Cpicture%2Ccreated_time%2Cshares%2Clikes%2Cactions)

I get message, picture, created_time, shares, and likes but with the last : **actions**, the graph api writes : **field is empty or disallowed by the access-token**.

It works with the access-token of my Facebook account with the permission **user_friends** enabled.

On my app's *authorizations parameters* on [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) I tried to set :

user_actions.news, manage_pages, read_stream, and user_friends

But I still can't get the **actions** field.

==>Which parameter should I set to get this field with the same access token ?

Thx

--It's my First Ask

--I'm French and trying to speak English, sorry for grammar

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using the "id" field given with the request :

```
graph.facebook.com/bordeauxmaville?fields=posts.limit(1).fields(message,picture,created_time,shares,likes)&access_token=MYAPIKEY|MYAPPSECRET
```

I got : "10655XXXX47646_530492XXX87198"

I split it into two string :

```
String str1 = "10655XXXX47646";
String str2 = "530492XXX87198";
String link = "https://www.facebook.com/" + str1 + "/posts/" + str2
```

I finally got the same information as in the disallowed field named "actions".